# Is there a way in SAS to print the value of a variable in label using proc sql?

Tags: sas, label, proc

I  have a situation where I would like to put the value of a variable in the label in SAS.
Example: Median for Total_Days is 2. I would like to put this value in Days_Median_Split label. The median keeps on changing with varying data, so I would like to automate it.

- Phy_Activity Total_Days "Days_Median_Split:  Number of Days with Median 2"
- No   0   0
- No   0   0
- Yes  2   1
- Yes  3   1
- Yes  5   1

[Sample Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaiTl.png)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, this is very much possible, but it's definitely some work. Showing at least some effort would be appreciated and then we can help you further. Not sure what you want us to do with an image of your data either - provide data as text please. Examples 1 & 8 here will get you started. http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/173-2008.pdf

Comment: Sure, i will look into the link ..thanks for this.. The data image is just to display the label (ie. how I want to label the variable as - Days_Median_Split: 
Number of Days with Median 2) as 2 is derived from other variable.

Comment: You called it a sample data set, not sample expected output....

Comment: I think that was obvious, as I put the statement -- Example: Median for Total_Days is 2. I would like to put this value in Days_Median_Split label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* step 1 create data;
data have;
input Phy_Activity $ Total_Days Days_Median_Split;
datalines;
No 0 0
No 0 0
Yes 2 1
Yes 3 1 
Yes 5 1
run;

*step 2 sort data on Total_days;
proc sort data = have;
by Total_days;
run;

*step 3 get count of obs;
proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into: cnt
from have;quit;

* step 4 calulate median;
%let median = %sysevalf(&cnt/2 + .5);


*step 5 get median obsevation;
proc sql noprint;
select Total_days into: medianValue
from have
where monotonic()=&median;quit;

*step 6 create label;
data have;
set have;
label Days_Median_split = 'Days_Median_split: Number of Days with Median '  
%trim(&medianValue);
run;
```

Comment: In step 4 make sure you end up with an integer.  change %let median = %sysevalf(&cnt/2 + .5);   to %let median = %sysevalf(&cnt/2 + .5,floor);

Comment: sure, for now I am using proc sql with median function.. will try both ways